# java passing JFrame acceptable?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I've got a class that extends JFrame...

I then assign it to a variable

```
JFrame frame = this;
```

I now need to pass this frame into an actionListener class called LoginListener but to do that I need to pass it to a class AppLoginComponents first that extends JPanel and this class has an instance of LoginListener(information,signin, frame)

So it's like this

Class extending Frame -> AppLoginComponents -> LoginListener

The reason i'm doing this is that the LoginListener needs to quit the application if the user hasn't logged in within 2 minutes.  I am planning to dispose the frame.  I don't think a static variable would be ideal would it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, don't use a static variable. Yes, it's fine to pass references around. You can also get a reference to the containing top level window via a `SwingUtility` method, called `getWindowAncestor(Component c)`.

But this begs a question -- why have a class extend JFrame? Are you overriding any of JFrame's methods?

Comment: Only overriding add,setSize, setVisible and pack methods.  I didn't know about getWindowAncestor, thanks!

Comment: Is it preferred to pass references around or use SwingUtility's getWindowAncestor?

Comment: So you're actually overriding those methods, not simply calling them in the class's constructor? I don't know which is preferred to be honest. I think that you can't call getWindowAncestor before the GUI has been rendered (pack() or setVisible(true) called on the top-level window), else you're liable to get a null.

Comment: Sorry i'm not overriding the JFrame methods, yep i'm calling them in the classes constructor.